# Akka TestKit Testing Multiple Actor Message Responses

Tags: akka

I have an Actor that takes in a message and does a context become as soon as it gets that message. After that I spin up an Observable and in that Observable, I keep sending this Actor some specific messages until I get to a desired state. I then started to write unit tests to test this Actor behavior, but I would like to know how I can check the expectations. So here is my test Actor:

```
"start to RampUp when a Dispatch command is sent" in {
  rampUpTypeSimActor ! Dispatch(rampUpTypeCfg.maxPower)
  expectMsgPF(12.seconds) {
    case state: PowerPlantState =>
      // check the signals
      assert(
        state.signals(activePowerSignalKey).toDouble === 800.0,
        "expecting activePower to be 800.0, but was not the case"
      )
      assert(
        state.signals(isDispatchedSignalKey).toBoolean,
        "expected isDispatched signal to be true, but was false instead"
      )
      assert(
        state.signals(isAvailableSignalKey).toBoolean,
        "expected isAvailable signal to be true, but was false instead"
      )
      assert(
        state.rampRate === initPowerPlantState.rampRate,
        "rampRate did not match"
      )
      assert(
        state.setPoint === initPowerPlantState.setPoint,
        "setPoint did not match"
      )
    case x: Any => // If I get any other message, I fail
      fail(s"Expected a PowerPlantState as message response from the Actor, but the response was $x")
  }
}
```

How can I wait for 15 seconds after sending the Dispatch command? I need to send another command called Status so that I can check my expectations, but I want to wait for 15 seconds and then send the Status message to my actor!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it. I had to move the Dispatch(...) command into a within block:

```
  within(12.seconds) {
    rampUpTypeSimActor ! Dispatch(rampUpTypeCfg.maxPower)
    expectNoMsg
  }
```

And then send a Status message to the Actor to check the expectations!